# rails - Executing multiple model methods in a begin/rescue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have multiple model methods and I want to loop and execute through each of them. How would I perform this in rails 2.3.11? Preferably in a begin/rescue.

Edit:

Thanks maprihoda, I used your example and was able to apply it with the begin/rescue:

```
class MyModel
  def method_1
    puts 'In method_1'
  end

  def method_2
    puts 'In method_2'
  end

  def method_3
    %w( method_1 method_2).each { |m| 
      begin
        self.send(m)
      rescue => e
        puts "#{e.message}"
      end
    }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
class MyModel
  def method_1
    puts 'In method_1'
  end

  def method_2
    puts 'In method_2'
  end

  def method_3
    %w( method_1 method_2).each { |m| self.send(m) }
  end
end

my_model = MyModel.new
my_model.method_3
```